# Does developments means building?

Tags: meaning

This video (https://youtu.be/SY_iFntJ8xY?t=148) is talking about some Real Estate Tips.

> all the garbage and water
>   bills are also paid directly by you and
>   not an HOA. however, in some **developments**
>   mostly newer ones, there's a small HOA fee usually this is
>   paid by the neighborhood to maintain a
>   local park and the greenery near the
>   roadway

Does developments mean the building?

So, I can use the word **developments** this way

> Condos,  Townhouses, Detached Homes are 3 main types of developments.

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost.  It's not quite "the building" because it could refer to multiple buildings built as part of the same project.  For example if builders laid out some new streets with 30 new detatched homes on them, the whole block of 30 houses plus the infrastructure built for them (streets, sewers etc) would be "the development" as far as any homeowner there was concerned.